# Developing two Second-Generation Managed Packages from one Dev Hub instance

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

We are developing two Managed Packages with Version 2.0 from a Single Dev Hub instance.

- Package 1 will be published on AppExchange as a "Paid Add On".
- Package 2 will be a Managed Package which will be not published on AppExchange but shared with the Customers directly(could be Paid or free).
- There will be a slight difference in both the Packages in terms of features and functionalities.

I have two queries regarding the above implementation which I'm trying to get any answers for:-

- Since both the packages relate to the same Dev Hub instance where
  one of them is listed on AppExchange, so, will Salesforce allow us to
  Manage the second "Managed Package" from the Same Dev Hub Instance as
  well because the second one will not be listed on AppExchange?
- Do we need to share with Salesforce about the second "Namespace" org or
  the second Managed Package which not be listed on AppExchange other
  than the first which will be listed on AppExchange but both getting
  managed from the same Dev Hub Instance?

Any suggestions or feedback would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Everything should just work for the most part. The one thing you will need to do though is attach the second package to an AppExchange listing (it doesn't need to be public) in order to be able to login to customer orgs via support access and get logs etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to manage several packages from the same Dev Hub. You do not have to publish them all on the AppExchange if you don't want to. You do not have to inform Salesforce about your other packages either.